# How Entity Framework 5 DbContext manage database connection?

Tags: entity-framework

In a asp.net mvc application, I use EF5, and create one DbContext instance per http request.  My code wont worry about open/close the database connection because that is handled by EF itself.

My questions:

1. If I have multiple database read/write operations by using DbSet in one http request . Does every operations require a open/close database connection? In one http request, could end up so many open/close which is expensive.
2. If yes to the question above, can i manually manage the open/close database connection myself, so that it will open at the begin_request and close at the end_request?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, but it is handled by connection pool so don't worry. Save Changes happens over single open connection for many entities.
2. No, it may be possible but will be difficult to implement it is as very internal and not documented. You can browse source and try, but not worth it, you will hold connections open for long and Connection pool may Suffer from it.

We have production Servers with EF4 and we don't see performance issues for nearly 1000 simultaneous requests that peek in a day time.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage connection manually on Entity Framework 6, by using the following contructor of DbContext:

```
DbContext(DbConnection, Boolean)
```

There is an example (pseudo code):

```
// ...
var myConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
var myDbContext = new MyDbContext(myConnection, false);
// ...
// TODO: you must close and dispose "myConnection" manually
```

Where MyDbContext is:

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext 
{
   // ....

   // constructor
   MyDbContext(DbConnection conn, boolean contextOwnsConnection)
     : base (conn, contextOwnsConnection) 
   {
      // ...
   }

   // ....

}
```

If you use "true" as contextOwnsConnection, the connection is closed when our DbContext is disposed.

For help about the boolean parameter, please se the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx

Note that we can use several DbContexts with the same connection by using this approach.

Note also that we can use the connection according to database we are connecting with. In the following example, we installed ODP for Entity Framework to use Oracle:

```
var myConnection = new OracleConnection(myConnectionString);
```